# Firestore Document Size Limitations

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I've Google Cloud Firestore Project. My database model is like this:

[image]

Each store has own document. **Sales** and **inventory** collections has a lot of documents and their size increases every day.

There is document max size limitation for documents in Firestore. So, Document that named **Store1** has sales and inventory collections and they store every sale and item. Does **Store1** document have max size limitation? Would **sales** and **inventory** documents size increasing be a problem? If it would be, my data model should be incorrect and if it's incorrect, how should it be?

Comment: If you are worried about the size of the document, you can always check against the maximum 1 MiB quota using the [FirestoreDocument-Android](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreDocument-Android/tree/master/firestore-document) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document size limitation in Firestore is enforced per individual document, and does not include the size of the documents in subcollections of that document. It is relatively uncommon for folks to hit the document size limit.

Comment: Are indexes on the document fields included in this 1 Mb limit? We've reached a 1MB limit on a much smaller document that has a size 50 Kb (the document size is calculated by traversing and summing up document tree node recursively )

Comment: I don't think so.